# SD card: unable to read partition table

Tags: filesystems, sd-card

I have one micro sd card which my laptop does not read and neither mount nor show in `lsblk`or `blkid`. Using `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, shows that there are problems:

```
[ 3250.544073] tifm_core: MMC/SD card detected in socket 0:3
[ 3250.689963] mmc0: new SDHC card at address 0007
[ 3250.693295] mmcblk0: mmc0:0007 SD16G 14.4 GiB 
[ 3250.695323] mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 0, nr 8, cmd response 0x900, card status 0xb00
[ 3250.763994] mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 0, nr 8, cmd response 0x900, card status 0xb00
[ 3250.764048] mmcblk0: retrying using single block read
[ 3250.764462] mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 0, nr 8, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
[ 3250.764901] mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 1, nr 7, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
[ 3250.765534] mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 2, nr 6, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
[ 3250.765963] mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 3, nr 5, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
[ 3250.766391] mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 4, nr 4, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
[ 3250.766817] mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 5, nr 3, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
[ 3250.767246] mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 6, nr 2, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
[ 3250.767672] mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 7, nr 1, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
[ 3251.776249] tifm_sd0:3 : card failed to respond for a long period of time (12, 9)
[ 3251.776273] tifm0 : demand removing card from socket 0:3
[ 3251.776372] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.776381] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.776389] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, aborting
[ 3251.776530] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.776539] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.776546] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, aborting
[ 3251.776573] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 3251.776638] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.776646] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.776654] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, aborting
[ 3251.776737] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.776745] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.776752] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, aborting
[ 3251.776836] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.776844] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.776852] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, aborting
[ 3251.776934] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.776942] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.776950] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, aborting
[ 3251.776974] Dev mmcblk0: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 3251.777041] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.777049] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.777056] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, aborting
[ 3251.777138] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.777147] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.777154] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, aborting
[ 3251.777248] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.777257] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.777264] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, aborting
[ 3251.777346] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.777355] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.777362] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, aborting
[ 3251.777444] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.777452] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 3251.777460] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, aborting
[ 3251.777484] mmcblk0: unable to read partition table
[ 3251.781293] mmc0: card 0007 removed
systemd-udevd[2305]: inotify_add_watch(9, /dev/mmcblk0, 10) failed: No such file or directory
[ 3251.844043] tifm_core: MMC/SD card detected in socket 0:3
[ 3252.089018] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[ 3252.269558] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
```

I tried several things (e.g. `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`) or adding *tifm_sd* to `/etc/modules`., none of them successful. The sd card (Sony micro sd, HC, 16 GB, 90 MB/s, SR 16UY3 works fine on my Android phone and in my camera, but not on my laptop (Ubuntu 18.04, Acer TravelMate 4500). Also with *GParted*, I cannot see the card. Other sd cards work fine on the laptop.

Information on the sd card reader (I also updated the driver to exclude that possible cause) via `lspci`:

```
CardBus bridge [0607]: Texas Instruments PCIxx21/PCIxx11/PCIx515 PC Card Controller [104c:8031]
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Extensa 3000 series laptop [1025:0064]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 168, IRQ 10
    Memory at e0209000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Bus: primary=02, secondary=03, subordinate=06, sec-latency=176
    Memory window 0: 80000000-83ffffff (prefetchable)
    Memory window 1: 90000000-93ffffff
    I/O window 0: 00003000-000030ff
    I/O window 1: 00003400-000034ff
    16-bit legacy interface ports at 0001
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: yenta_cardbus
    Kernel modules: yenta_socket
```

**Thanks** for your hints! And please tell me if you need any other information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty old laptop: according to Google, it seems to have the Pentium M 715 CPU, which was released in June 2004, and the Intel 855GME chipset was released in 2003.

The specification for SDHC memory card sub-type was announced in 2006, so it is very likely the built-in card reader in the laptop is just too old to support SDHC cards: it is very likely that sub-type of SD cards did not even exist yet back when the card reader chip of the laptop was designed.

The SDHC specification [redefines the way the card's Card-Specific Data register is used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_card#Storage_capacity_calculations): this tends to cause older card readers to not recognize SDHC cards unless there is a firmware update for the card reader.